# Linux Sockets/Connections

Tags: linux, sockets

I have a gateway server that is also acting as a web proxy for clients and I need to get some information about the network connections. The gateway server has an internal and an external interface/IP-address.

If I use the 'netstat' or 'ss' command I get a display showing of all the clients' internal IP addresses/ports connecting to the gateway's internal IP address/squid-port. But if I run 'iftop' I get a display of the clients' internal IP addresses and the external IP address/port they are ultimately connecting to, it seems to ignore the proxy middleman.

The information from iftop is what I need, that is, internal ip:port to final ip:port ignoring the proxy, but I need to parse the output and can't seem to do that with iftop as it is interactive. Does anyone know a way to get iftop like information from a standard Linux command?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a typical HTTP proxy setup, `ss -at` will show two entries: one for client--proxy, and one for proxy--webpage, just as it should, because two connections are live in such a case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I can't see both connections, I now have the feeling I may need to do a packet capture/analysis :-(